# How do I collapse rows of a pivot table in VisiData?

Tags: visidata

I have generated a Pivot Table in VisiData, and I want to collapse the rows.

Data that looks like:

```
 20 ║ 360 |   0 |   0 ║
 20 ║   0 | 299 |   0 ║
 20 ║   0 |   0 |  17 ║
 19 ║   0 | 711 |   0 ║
 19 ║ 586 |   0 |   0 ║
 19 ║   0 |   0 |  59 ║
 18 ║   0 | 1054|   0 ║
 18 ║ 905 |   0 |   0 ║
 18 ║   0 |   0 |  82 ║
```

I want it to be:

```
20 ║ 360 ║ 299 ║ 17 ║
19 ║ 586 ║ 711 ║ 59 ║
...
```

I've tried various aggregation methods, but none of them seem to be working.

Comment: Fun tip: You can copy data out of VisiData in Markdown format, which will generate nicely formatted tables when pasted into StackOverflow. 1. Select the desired rows (`s`). 2. Copy the rows to the system clipboard with `Y` (`Shift-Y`). 3. At the bottom of the screen, it will say `copy 1 sheets as filetype: tsv`. Change `tsv` to `md`, then press `Enter`. 4. Paste into StackOverflow and enjoy nicely formatted tables!

Comment: @daviewales Nice tip. I was copying text from the console VisiData UI by holding down "Shift" similar to how we'd do it in mitmproxy console UI. This is much better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the instructions on [Group](https://www.visidata.org/docs/group/) in the VisiData documentation and asked in the IRC channel.

What worked was to add a 'max' aggregation on the (last) three columns and then hit Shift+F which gives a table like:

```
t  #║  F_max# | N_max#  | C_max#  ║
 10 ║      22 |      29 |       2 ║
 11 ║     806 |    1162 |      98 ║
 12 ║     248 |     288 |      18 ║
 13 ║     137 |     130 |       8 ║
 14 ║     824 |     888 |      58 ║
 15 ║     567 |     779 |      41 ║
 16 ║     514 |     359 |     304 ║
 17 ║     421 |     263 |      13 ║
 18 ║     905 |    1054 |      82 ║
 19 ║     586 |     711 |      59 ║
 20 ║     360 |     299 |      17 ║
```